# Why my assigning an object itself doesn't work properly?

Tags: c++, c++20, assignment-operator

AFAIK, for an operator that doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of its operand(s), we should not modify the operand more than once.

Here I have this snippet that I wrote:

- I'm compiling it using gcc with the C++20 standard: `-std=c++2b`.

```cpp
int main(){
    std::string s = "hello";
    auto beg = s.begin();
    *beg = *beg++;
    std::cout << s << "  " << *beg << std::endl;
}
```

Why do I get this output?

```
hhllo  h
```

This:

```cpp
*beg = (*beg)++;
std::cout << s << " " << *beg << '\n';
```

yields this output:

```
hello  h
```

- Why is the value `'h'` not incremented to `'i'`?
- What happens here? Normally, this assigns the first character in `s` back to itself then increments the `beg` iterator. But the iterator is not incremented, but the value changed! I bet that it is because of *Undefined Behavior*, but if so then can someone explain this to me?
- Did the C++17 standard add the assignment operator to the 'sequenced' operators? If so, why doesn't it work properly in my example?

Comment: Why does it matter? Nobody should ever write that code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Could you please explain? *beg = *beg++; I'm only modifying *beg only once?! and increment `beg`?

Comment: Yes, assignment is sequenced in C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order. (That means no UB if compiling for ≥C++17.)

Comment: @chris But I've compiled it using C++ 20: `-std=c++2b`.

Comment: Why did you expect a different result then? The changes in C++17 state that the right hand side is evaluated first, so `beg` on the left hand side points at the second character

Comment: @UnholySheep: So is it safe? and there is no UB in my code under C++17 and above?

Comment: You really need to be more specific. Such an important detail that you're building with C++20 should have been mentioned in the question itself. Perhaps even added as a tag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: OK thanks. I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes, it's safe, though of questionable usefulness, since you yourself did not know what behavior to expect of your own code (although the second code snippet seems to be more of a confusion about what postfix increment returns)

Comment: In the second example, `*beg` on the RHS evaluates to `'h'`.  Then you increment `*beg`, so now `s[0] == 'i'`.  The value of the RHS is still `'h'`.  Now you assign this value back to `*beg`, so now `s[0] == 'h'` again.  You did successfully increment the character, but then you overwrote it with its original value.

Comment: @PeteBecker: But the standard changed: since C++17 the assignment operator has been added to the sequenced operators.

Comment: The code is unsafe in the sense that if a colleague knows you wrote it, said colleague might come hit your head with a C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these results are correct. Your misunderstanding comes from not knowing how postfix increment works.

> ```
> *beg = *beg++;
> ```

By the rules of C++ operator precedence, postfix operators happen first. So this is `*beg = *(beg++)`.

C++17 forced assignment operators to completely evaluate all expressions on the right-hand side, including all side-effects, before evaluating the left-hand side.

Postfix iterator increment increments the lvalue, but it returns a copy of the *original value*. The original value is an iterator pointing at the first character. So after evaluating `beg++`, `beg` will have changed its position (therefore pointing at the second character). But the *value of the expression* is an iterator pointing at the first.

Then this iterator is derefenced, thus returning a reference to the first character.

After that, the lhs is evaluated. `beg` as previously noted, points to the second character. So `*beg` is a reference to the second character, which gets assigned to the value of the first character.

---

> ```
> *beg = (*beg)++;
> ```

So this is the other way around. `*beg` is a reference to the first character, which is then postfix incremented. This means that the object referenced by `*beg` is incremented, but the *value of the expression* is a copy of the *original value*. Namely, the character as it was before being incremented: `'h'`.

You then assign this character to the first character, therefore overwriting what you just incremented.

BTW: if you have to go into this detail to figure out what an expression is doing, you shouldn't write your expression that way. Avoid postfix expressions unless they are absolutely essential in some way.

Comment: Believe me I do really know how the postfix increment/decrement operators work but was confused whether it is undefined behavior or not (sequenced or not) on different C++ Standards. Thank you so much for such explanation.